# how to show banner ads programmatically

Tags: android, smartbanner

I am trying to implement banner ad but it is messing up with my main layout which is a DrawView. Either mAdview is displayed or DrawView, but not together. I want to show them together.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    size = getIntent().getIntExtra("SIZE", 3);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tile);
    drawView = new DrawView(this, size);
    setContentView(drawView);
    setTileSize();

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

}
```

XML created

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<view class="com.kilnake.patta.picpuzz.TileActivity$DrawView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you did not understand how [setContentView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int)) works...

Comment: do u have the key and all that set up on your Application level?

Comment: sorry.. guide me, which key? .. and yes i am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

One problem you face here is how you use [setContentView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int)). This function define which layout to display for this activity. What you do is :

1. `setContentView(R.layout.activity_tile);` : you tell to display the layout define in the file activity_tile.xml (what you call your main layout).
2. `setContentView(drawView);` : Tell to change what to display, stop display your main layout and display the DrawView
3. `setContentView(layouut);` : Cahnge again to stop display the DrawView and display `layouut` (which contains only the adView)

You need to call this function only once. Define your whole layout in the xml file, by adding the DrawView and the Adview in this file. Then use only `setContentView(R.layout.activity_tile);`

Comment: i somehow got the concept, and tried as you said and made new xml which has "view" (but not draw view)and ad. but it is crashing at view in xml, where am i wrong?

Comment: Since I don't know what your xml file looks like, neither what your new activity class looks like, I can't tell you what you're doing wrong... Can you edit your question to show us your xml file ?